# Вставка данных в связанные таблицы mysql через web-форму

Tags: php, mysql

Как реализовать вставку данных в связанные таблицы *mysql* через web-форму таким образом, чтобы `id` строки, к которой необходимо связать вставляемые данные, вычислялось при введении значений в несколько строк, в которых имеется функция автозаполнения?

**Например:** Необходимо получить `id` строки организации "Пупкин и Ко" в которой работает "Василий Бенедиктович", а пользователь вводит только в соответствующей форме "Васил" и с помощью автозаполнения выбирает из обнаруженных строк "Василий Бенедиктович". Далее к `id` этой строки через веб-форму добавляются иные данные.

Comment: Ищете в базе все id для котороых ФИО начинается/содержит Васил, т.е. что то типа `select id from table where fio like 'Васил%'`